# Compare duplicate items in a list of weighted edge

Tags: python, duplicates, edge-list

I created a weighted edge list of lists with:

```
for key1, value1 in x1.items():
   for key2, value2 in x2.items():
      weight = 1 / (value1 + value2)
      row.append((key1, key2, str(weight)))
```

After that the list of lists contain duplicates. For example:

```
[(a,a,0.5), ..., (a,b,0.2),..., (b,a,0.2), ..., (z,z,0.5)]
```

My approach doesn't work:

```
i = 0
j = 0
for row1 in matrix:
    for row2 in matrix:
        if(matrix[i][0] == matrix[j][1]):
           del(matrix[j])
        j +=1
    i +=1
```

I'll get this massage:

```
if(matrix[i][0] == matrix[j][1]):

IndexError: list index out of range
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to provide sample input data and a runnable [mre].

Comment: We can't tell you what you're doing wrong, because you haven't told us what you're trying to do.  Your immediate problem is that you need to set `j=0` for each row, between the two `for` statements.

Comment: Thank you both very much.
What a mistake... j=0 has to be set between the to for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the value of `j` might be returned to zero every time.

```
i = 0
for row1 in matrix:
    j = 0
    for row2 in matrix:
        if(matrix[i][0] == matrix[j][1]):
           print(matrix[i][0], matrix[j][1])
        j +=1
    i +=1
```